# I got the following error while running the command to start Jboss EAP 6.1

Tags: multithreading, jboss, jboss6.x

I got the following error while running the command to start Jboss EAP 6.1
 from home path ./domain.sh

```
 ERROR [org.jboss.as.host.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS010932: Caught exception during boot: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: JBAS014676: Failed to parse configuration
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with the configuration of the domain.xml file. Have you edited it?

It can help to find the problem if you post the whole "Host Controller" log information and the domain.xml file.